# Why javax.servlet package is distributed only as part of application servers?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets

I'm not new to servlets. But I'm still curious: why `javax.servlet` package isn't distributed on its own? Why I need some application server installed before I can compile my code?

Comment: Because it's intended to run for Web Applications on a Java Web Application Server, not outside. Still, you can have this package in the Java EE 6 JDK (that is a GlassFish v3 implementation).

Comment: @GlebR - Application Server implement JEE specification and javax.Servlet can only run  on these kind of servers

Comment: It is distributed on its own. Your question is based on a false premiss.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer, it is distributed separately.

Servlets are a specification and an API. If you want the JAR, download it from the spec site [Servlet Spec 3.0](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/servlet-3.0-fr-eval-oth-JSpec/).

Obviously if you want to actually deploy your application, you'll still need an implementation (i.e. a server).

Answer (score 2):

The servlet API is available through some jar and you can do with it what you want. On maven it is [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/servlet-api). You can compile the code without any application server but it probably won't do what you want. It is only an interface afterall

Servlets are only really relevant in the context of a Web Application and this is why Servlet Containers exist. They are the implementation. Take a look at all the work the container does before a request reaches the servlet: [Tomcat Sequence Diagram](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/architecture/requestProcess/requestProcess.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

Servlets like other Java EE technology like EJB are Specification from [JSR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSR)(Java Specification Requests) from [Java Community Process Program](http://www.jcp.org/)

The onus is on the Application Server vendor to provide the implementation based on the specifications released.In this case
 - for [Servlet 2.5](http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/mrel/jsr154/index.html) 
 - for [Servlet 3.0](http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr315/index.html)

Sun / now Oracle does release the `javax.servlet` package separately and you can download it from [Maven Repository](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/servlet-api) also its available within the lib folder of any J2ee complaint application server/web container .
i.e for Tomcat its available in **TOMCAT_HOMEDIR/lib/servlet-api**

So for `developing and compiling , this jar is sufficient` , you would only `need the Application server only when you want to actually deploy your application`.